# Failed to read row 0, column 4294967295 from a window with 1 rows, 7 columns

Tags: java, sqlite

I used this code but whenever I try to click the button
the error "Failed to read row 0, column 4294967295 from a window with 1 rows, 7 columns" always appear on logcat and the app goes back to the previous  layout

This database base is for the questions in my database and i want it to display on the buttons

```
public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "Login.db";
    private static final String TABLE_QUESTION = "questionbank";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String CHOICE1 = "choice1";
    private static final String CHOICE2 = "choice2";
    private static final String CHOICE3 = "choice3";
    private static final String CHOICE4 = "choice4";
    private static final String ANSWER = "answer";
    public MyDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase MyDB) {
        MyDB.execSQL("create Table users(name TEXT primary key, age TEXT, school
                TEXT)");
        MyDB.execSQL("create Table questionbank(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                AUTOINCREMENT, question TEXT, choice1 TEXT, choice2 TEXT, choice3 TEXT, choice4
                TEXT, answer TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase MyDB, int i, int i1) {
        MyDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
        MyDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST questionbank");
        onCreate(MyDB);
    }
    public long addInitialQuestion(Question question) {
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues questions = new ContentValues();
        questions.put(QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        questions.put(CHOICE1, question.getChoice(0));
        questions.put(CHOICE2, question.getChoice(1));
        questions.put(CHOICE3, question.getChoice(2));
        questions.put(CHOICE4, question.getChoice(3));
        questions.put(ANSWER, question.getAnswer());
        long insert = MyDB.insert(TABLE_QUESTION, null, questions);
        return insert;
    }
    public Boolean insertuserdata(String name, String age, String school) {
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("age", age);
        contentValues.put("school", school);
        long result = MyDB.insert("users", null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestionsList () {
        List<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTION;
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = MyDB.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question question = new Question();
                String questText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QUESTION));
                question.setQuestion(questText);
                String choice1Text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE1));
                question.setChoice(0, choice1Text);
                String choice2Text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE2));
                question.setChoice(1, choice2Text);
                String choice3Text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE3));
                question.setChoice(2, choice3Text);
                String choice4Text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CHOICE4));
                question.setChoice(3, choice4Text);
                String answerText = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ANSWER));
                question.setAnswer(answerText);
                questionArrayList.add(question);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
            Collections.shuffle(questionArrayList);
        }
        return questionArrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsigned 32-bit `4294967295` is the same as signed 32-bit `-1`. Looks like one of your `getColumnIndex()` returned -1 because the column didn't exist in the cursor. Might be because you have modified the table schema but didn't uninstall/reinstall your app to recreate the database file.

Comment: i did modify the database but didnt reinstall since I dont know have

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are reading some column that is not existing. Could it be that you changed your column names, but did not delete the application before reinstalling it? I would uninstall the application  manually on the phone/emulator and reinstall it to check if the error is gone.

Comment: how do you uninstall the app I'm using android studio

Comment: Do you use the emulator? Normally, you do a long click on the application icon on the smartphone screen and then select delete or drag to delete.

Comment: yes i use emulator

Comment: Usually, you can go to the Menu (on screen) in your emulator, search for the application you developed and uninstall it manually. Probably, bad wording on my side... It is probably not called delete but uninstall.